# Subant targets instead of ant

Tags: ant

I 'm having a problem with subant and have no ideas any more. Can anyone help?
Using Ant to replace some strings for other (i.e Productname and Version for "Foo" and "1.2") I used such thing:

```
<copy todir="${Foo_Home}\cm_builds\Deployment\Database\Production.win\">
    <fileset dir="${Foo_Home}\Deployment\Database\Production.win\"
             includes="**/*.sql,**/*.cmd"/>
    <filterset>
        <filter token="PRODUCTNAME" value="Foo"/>
        <filter token="VERSION" value="1.2"/>
    </filterset>
</copy>
```

Can we do the same by means of subant? Because `copy` and `replacetoken` etc. are not supported by subant.  But we need exactly subant...

Something like this:

```
<subant target="build" genericantfile="build.xml">
  <dirset dir="${Foo_Home}\cm_builds\Deployment\Database\Production.win\"
          includes ="**/*.sql">
</subant>
```

Is that the right way to use subant? (Assume we have several targets like this)

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/subant.html for help =)

#### Update:

I suspect i use subant in a wrong way. Maybe there is no need to try to make subant run the same task as ant does? Maybe i should make subant run ant in a required directory and don't change anything for ant?

Comment: Did you forget to include the example?

Answer (score 5):

I don't understand what it is that you are trying to do, or what you mean by "copy and replacetoken etc are not supported by subant". The `subant` task is used to invoke an Ant build in multiple directories. For example, suppose you have a property `${top}` that points to a directory that contains subdirectories named `one`, `two`, and `three`. Then you could use a `subant` task to invoke Ant in each of those subdirectories like this:

```
<subant genericantfile="${top}/build.xml" target="build">
    <!-- include all subdirectories in ${top} -->
    <dirset dir="${top}"/>
</subant>
```

This would be roughly equivalent to the following commands at a command prompt (assuming that the directory `top` is located in `/work/top`):

```
$ cd /work/top
$ cd one
$ ant -f ../build.xml build
$ cd ../two
$ ant -f ../build.xml build
$ cd ../three
$ ant -f ../build.xml build
```

Finally, your usage of `dirset` is incorrect. A [dirset](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/dirset.html) is a group of directories, not files, so your `dirset` above will include all *directories* that end with `.sql`, which I suspect is not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Why doesn't the [replace task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replace.html) work for you?